# Using local dependency in a glide

Tags: go, package-managers, glide-golang

I'm new to golang and came across glide as a dependency management tool. 
In a scenario, where I have a package which I want to use as a dependency in my project.

Is there any way can I specify it?

If not using glide, is there any way to put it under dependency and use it? 
My ultimate goal is, if dependency works within my package, I would publish it and use it with `glide get <git_repo_url>`

Comment: Have you checked [How it works section of glide in github](https://github.com/Masterminds/glide#user-content-how-it-works) and also they have a sample [guide yaml file](https://github.com/Masterminds/glide#user-content-glideyaml)

Comment: @AmitThawait Yes, I had a look at it. But all examples show the github repo and local dependency.